# jQuery Doing delay in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I need to click every item of my array but in the delay so I created delay function and after the delay time it's clicking the first element but then it is not waiting another delay time, instead of that it just bursts rest of the items.

Thanks from above for the help. I just want click, 15s, click itp.

Here's my code:

```
function doSetTimeout(i){setTimeout(function(){array[i].click()}, 15000);}
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) doSetTimeout(i);
```

Comment: `function doSetTimeout(i){setTimeout(function(){array[i].click()}, 15000 * i);}` or `15000 * (i+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increse your timeout in your `setTimeout` function, because otherwise in your second and further calls the time of 15s is already reached and it will execute immediatelly:

```
function doSetTimeout(i){setTimeout(function(){array[i].click()}, 15000 * (i+1));}
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) doSetTimeout(i);
```

See [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   after a specified number of milliseconds.

Comment: Yea man but I always thought that setInterval is running to the end of the world every delay time.

Comment: Ahh so it works like that - it does not reset the timer or something and continue but it just thinks that 15s passed so it is time to fire the function?

Comment: I just wrote the same thing but thanks man you helped me, it works.